# GDB with C++ substring passed to function gets overflow in printers.py to_string

Tags: c++, printing, gdb, strstr

In GDB, I can print a substring, like so:

```
(gdb) print outStaticValue.substr(off,len)
$16 = "L"
```

But when I pass that substring to a function (say, second argument `spec` of `edit_amt_justify`) by value, the target function's argument variable is unprintable.  I get the following overflow error stepping into the function, and if I attempt to print `spec` separately, I get the same error:

```
edit_amt_justify (amt=..., spec=Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/gdb/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py", line 469, in to_string
    return self.val['_M_dataplus']['_M_p'].string (encoding, length = len)
OverflowError: signed integer is greater than maximum
, mp=0x89d6d0) at fmp_mapping_v3_class.cpp:3594
(gdb) next
(gdb) print spec
$17 = Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/gdb/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py", line 469, in to_string
    return self.val['_M_dataplus']['_M_p'].string (encoding, length = len)
OverflowError: signed integer is greater than maximum
```

The only thing I've been able to do to get around it is to put a temp string variable in the target function and assign the passed `spec` variable to it and then I can inspect the temp variable, e.g.:

```
std::string tmpstr = spec;
```

But that's tantamount to using the old `printf` approach of old, where it required adding custom code to debug your program.

> GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.0.1-42.el5)

Is there a way to remedy this error?